# Python: Place uninitialized class in variable

Tags: python, function, class, variables

Edit: It was pointed out that this was a silly for-loop mistake, everything works as you would expect. Thanks to @user2357112supportsMonica for sharp eyes :)

I'm trying to build a general function that can take in different mathematical models, implemented as classes and do calculations with them. To do this i have a local variable in my function called `model` that i set equal to the chosen model (as you could do if the models were implemented as functions). However, when i later try to initialise the `model` variable i get `TypeError: some_model object is not callable`. Here is an example of what i am trying to do:

```
from models import model1, model2, model3, ... #classes
import numpy as np

def do_calculations(components, model_key): #model_key is a string to choose a model
   if model_key == 'model1':
      model = model1 #not initialising on purpose
      print(model) # <class 'models.kempers89.kempers89'>
   elif model_key == 'model2':
      model = model2
   #And so on ...
   
   temperatures = np.linspace(0,10,100)
   for comp in components:
      model = model(comp) #TypeError 'model1' object is not callable
                          #But I'm trying to initialize, not call it!
         for T in temperatures:
            print(model.temp_calculation(T))
```

This example is simplified, but shows the point. I want to make a function that can do the same calculation with different classes. If the models were implemented as functions i wouldn't get this error (but that isn't an option due to backend fortran-code making things clumsy), why can't i pass a class to a variable as i can with a function? Example from part of one of the models:

```
class kempers89():

def __init__(self, comps = 'AR,HE', mole_frac = [0.5,0.5], eos_key = 'SRK', tot_moles = 1, min_temp = 50,
             temp = 298, pres = 1.01325e5, phase ='LIQUID'):

    self.comps = comps
    self.mole_frac = np.array(mole_frac)
    self.temp = temp
    self.pres = pres
    self.tot_moles = tot_moles

    self.eos = cubic.cubic()
    self.eos.init(comps, eos_key)
    self.eos.set_tmin(min_temp)
    self.phase = self.eos.get_phase_key(phase)

def temp_calculations(self):
    v, dvdn = self.eos.specific_volume(self.temp, self.pres, self.mole_frac, self.phase, dvdn=True)
    v1, v2 = dvdn
    mu, dmudn = self.eos.chemical_potential_tv(self.temp, v * self.tot_moles,
                                                            self.mole_frac * self.tot_moles, dmudn=True)
    x1_dmu1dx1 = dmudn[0,0] * self.tot_moles * self.mole_frac[0]
    enthalpies, dhdn = (self.eos.enthalpy_tv(self.temp, v, self.mole_frac, dhdn=True))
    h1, h2 = dhdn
    alpha_T = ((v1 * h2 - v2 * h1) / (np.dot(dvdn, self.mole_frac) * x1_dmu1dx1))
    ST = alpha_T / self.temp

    return ST
```

Comment: so, you've got files `model1.py` `model2.py`, `model3.py`. What's in those files? a class definition? to access those classes you'd need `model1.classname`

Comment: You absolutely can. You haven't provided a [mcve] so it is impossible to say what the problem is, but the idea you are asking about works. `class Foo: pass`, then `def call_class(klass): return klass()` and `call_class(Foo)` works just fine and as you would expect.

Comment: The error message implies *whatever* object you are passing isn't a class. Also, your import stamement doesn't make sense, `import model1, model2, model3 ...` isn't valid pyhton syntax.

Comment: "But I'm trying to initialize, not call it!" Those are the same things. You *call* class objects to initialize instances of that class.

Comment: i was a bit quick, sorry, edited my import statement. This however dosent fix the issue :/ adding some more code to the post now

Comment: @VegardJervell you have to add a [mcve]. Not necessarily more code. So far, you are describing some situation where you *believe* you are passing a class object to a function, but it is apparent you aren't. Or else you wouldn't get that error. We can only speculate without a [mcve]. I suppose, it is possible your classes have metaclasses that prevent them from being callable, but that is highly doubtful.

Comment: `model = model(comp)` overwrites your `model` variable. Don't reuse a variable name while you still need the old value.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica jeez, good catch

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Thank you! The error message was coming from the second for-loop iteration, not the first... I feel like i should have caught that myself now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code as simplified looks correct so maybe the bug is somewhere else. Some thoughts:

> But I'm trying to initialize, not call it!

Calling is /how/ you initialize. A class is a callable object, and calling the class creates instances of the class. But the way you are doing so looks right to me.

> TypeError 'model1' object is not callable

This is what I would expect to see if you actually did initialize the instance earlier, and are now handling an instance, not a class. Consider the following session at the interactive prompt:

```
>>> object
<class 'object'>
>>> object()
<object object at 0x10be78d10>
>>> object()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'object' object is not callable
>>>
```

So it looks like either model1, model2, etc. are instances and not classes, or your simplification eliminated the bug.

Comment: Turns out the problem was in the second iteration of the for loop. I was overwriting `model` when i initialized the first time, so of course it failed at the second iteration...

Answer (score 0):

model1, model2, and model3 are modules, not classes.  In each of them you should define a class named Model.  You can say `model.Model()`

Comment: mb, was a bit quick when writing into stackoverflow